# How can I have fixed background in a div?

Tags: css, html, background, background-position

I have a site, and in one of my pages I use a div which looks like an editor. I can have a background in this div and the content above it. I want this background to stay in a fixed position while I am scrolling in the div.

My code is similar to this:

```
 <div id="myEditorArea"  style="vertical-align: top; width: 240px; height: 320px;      background-image: url('image.png'); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: center center; background-attachment:fixed; overflow:scroll; text-align: left;">

 bla bla bla

 </div>
```

The background stays fixed and works ok when I scroll inside the div. The problem is that it is moving when I scroll in the whole page.

Does anyone know what could be the problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you link to the page, I'm not sure I understand the problem.

Comment: You forgot to end `style="..."`. You wrote `style="...`

Comment: Well is a bit complicated to link to the page. I have an example though. I found this link http://www.quackit.com/html/codes/html_background_codes.cfm and I want to do the same, as he does for the fixed background image. My problem is that this image is moving when I scroll the whole page and not only inside this div.

Comment: Ok I found the solution. I had to set the background-attachment to scroll instead of fixed, and together with the overflow:scroll it works. Not for IE yet. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of `background-attachment: fixed;` http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_background-attachment. That should be what you need.

Answer (score 0):

source : https://codyhouse.co/gem/alternate-fixed-scroll-backgrounds/

html:

```
<div class="cd-fixed-bg cd-bg-1">
        <h1><!-- title goes here --></h1>
    </div>
```

css:

```
body, html, main {
    /* important */
     height: 100%;
}

.cd-fixed-bg {
min-height: 100%;
background-size: cover;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center center;
}

.cd-fixed-bg.cd-bg-1 {
background-image: url("../img/cd-background-1.jpg");
}
```